# Using createNativeQuery with GRANT Statements

Tags: sql, jpa, sql-grant

I am working on fixing some code findings that were found by HP Fortify.

Trying to fix an existing query statement that performs a GRANT statement

Original Code:

```
Query grantQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("GRANT INSERT ON TABLE " + data + " TO " + username);
grantQuery.executeUpdate();
```

The variable data is just a string passed into this persistence class file.  The variable username is a private static final string of the persistence class file.  Also know this username property file is pulled from a local config file.

Fortify recommends using prepared statements instead of string concatenation.

I played with doing setParameters on the grantQuery but I just get errors in runtime.

Modified code to use setParameters:

```
Query grantQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("GRANT INSERT ON TABLE ?1 TO $2");
grantQuery.setParameter(1, data);
grantQuery.setParameter(2, username);
grantQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Error:
Rolling back transaction after exception. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryParameterException: could not locate named parameter [2]

Is my syntax wrong to use setParameters wrong?  Should I use be using another method to execute a GRANT statement?

Answer (score 1):

You put a `"$"` as the prefix for the second parameter, when should have a `"?"`

Comment: Thank you for catching that error.  An error came back that I saw before when using a different variable setParameter syntax

Comment: WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (RMI TCP Connection(19)-127.0.0.1) SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601

ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] (RMI TCP Connection(19)-127.0.0.1) ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Position: 23

ERROR [src.repo.Persistence] (RMI TCP Connection(19)-127.0.0.1) Rolling back transaction after exception.javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query

Comment: Which is seemingly not the same question, and if it is you have to at least post in your question what SQL is attempting to be executed and what this "$1" is

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't more clear.  $1 is a string value of the table name to allow the java application to persist its data in the database. So there is a GRANT and REVOKE statements depending on whether you want persistence on or off.  I just provided the GRANT statement since they are same syntax style.    $2 is the username for the database.

Comment: and as i said, JPA native queries does not use such $ syntax for parameters. If you are putting some value into SQL via parameter it has to be via a "?", hence the error

Comment: Really sorry for the typo.  I am using ? in the code not $ after you pointed out my mistake the first time but same error.   I guess the better question I should ask is can one use GRANT with prepared statements. I have not found any JPA documentation or example code that support this design.

Is this legal to do? 

Query grantQuery = entityManager.createNativeQuery("GRANT INSERT ON TABLE ?1 TO ?2");
grantQuery.setParameter(1, data);
grantQuery.setParameter(2, username);
grantQuery.executeUpdate();

I feel like I am going down the wrong rabbit whole on this.

Comment: you won't find any *JPA* documentation on that ... the issue is more what the JDBC driver supports (since that's all a JPA provider will use). Most JDBC drivers support parameters only in particular parts of a SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE statement, so no idea what your JDBC driver (and the datastore) accepts.

Comment: Ok, Ill check out some postgresql documentation.